# Azure App Services - Host free PHP Website

Tags: php, linux, azure, hosting

Is it possible to host a free php website with azure? Theoretically the App Services should be free for ever, but as soon as I select Linux when creating a new Instance it doesn't show any free option in the Pricing plans. Although there is a blog article which says there are free plans: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-app-service-update-free-linux-tier-python-and-java-support-and-more/

Comment: Did you deploy another linux app service in the free tier in the same region already? According to the docs there is one free plan per region: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits

Comment: I did already deploy another linux app, but not in the same region. Do you think I have to delete the existing one first? Also I cannot change the pricing tier of the existing app.

Comment: No, I believe that should be fine then since the limitation is per region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as per this MS Doc of App Service Plan Limits provided by @holger, 1 Linux Free App Service plan is per region basis.

[image]

I have checked that for some of the regions, Free SKU Tiers are not available in Dedicated App service plan and observed:

[image]

Comment: I was able to create a free app service plan as well. Afterwards I created a web app with "App Services > Create Web App". I think last time i directly started with the web app. There it is important to choose the same region and the same plan. Afterwards the free pricing tier is showing up.
I ended up using the dev/test price tier though since I need custom domains.